# Inconsistent behaviour with each and peach in KDB

Tags: kdb

As a minimal example, for instance if I have:

```
q) x:flip `a`b!(enlist 1;enlist 2);
q) y:flip `c`d!(enlist 3;enlist 4);
q) (raze x), (raze y)
`a`b`c`d!1j 2j 3j 4j   # works as expected
```

But with `peach` involved,

```
q) {(raze x), (raze y)} peach x
enlist 1j 2j   # I was expecting `a`b`c`d!1j 2j 3j 4j
```

There is no `3j 4j` in the output - why has my `raze y` been ignored?

Indeed, `each` also gives a different output

```
q) {(raze x), (raze y)} each x
({:(raze x), (raze y);}';flip `a`b!(enlist 1j;enlist 2j))
```

I thought `peach` was just a parallel version of `each`, so both should yield the same...

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was not an inconsistent behavior of peach and each.

**First**, Functions in kdb has implicit parameters as x,y,z if not specified any.

```
     So f:{x+y}  is equivalent to f:{[x;y] x+y}
     But f:{[a;b] a+b} will not have x,y,z as implicit parameter
```

For more details, see section Implicit Parameters in http://code.kx.com/q4m3/6_Functions/#617-implicit-parameters

**Peach Case:**
 When you do **{(raze x), (raze y)} peach x** :

i) Another way of writing  this function is:

```
    f:{[x;y] (raze x),(raze y)} 
    And call is like:  f[;] peach x
```

So you are passing global x to local x of a function but nothing in y, that's why you are getting only 1 and 2 and not 3 &4 in output.

ii) **Why only 1 and 2 and not `a`b!1 2 in output?**
   When you pass each row of table (x in your case) to a function, it goes in form of a dictionary. And raze on dictionary gives only values.

You have to modify your function for correct working like this(Use Each Both ):

```
             flip {x,y}' [x;y]
```

**' is each both** which is used when you have more then one arguments and you want to apply each on all of them simultaneoulsy.

This will take one row at a time from both global x and y and copy it to local x and y in dictionary form and then join them.

**Each Case:**

Each is just giving you message that your function requires 2 arguments and hence it couldn't execute it.

**Why Peach worked and Each didn't?**

Peach and Each are not same for some scenarios. 
When you have dyadic function, then peach works like **each prior(':)** and not as Each.
They are same only for monadic functions. In your case you have dyadic function.

Answer (score 1):

x and y can be implicit arguments to a function. Your use of x and y for the name of the list variables is confusing and not recommended.

To make it clear what is happening consider if I renamed the variables a,b:

```
q)a:flip `a`b!(enlist 1;enlist 2);
q)b:flip `c`d!(enlist 3;enlist 4);
q)(raze a), (raze b)
a| 1
b| 2
c| 3
d| 4
q){(raze a), (raze b)} peach x
a b c d
-------
1 2 3 4
```

You can see how peach/each handle the implicit function arguments with this example:

q)x:`x
q)y:`y

q){(x;y)} each 1
{(x;y)}'[1]
q){(x;y)} peach 1
1

I can't tell for sure what behaviour you want so all I can do is point out why there's an issue.

Comment: Thanks ryan, but in fact I was aware that `x` was an implicit argument, and was overloading as it made comparison between the three cases easier. Using your notation, I was expecting `{[x] (raze x), (raze b)} peach/each a` to be the same as `(raze a), (raze b)` yet all of these 3 cases appear to output differently. (Also, I made all tables just 1 row to make comparison easier.)